# Testing Windows 10 UWP purchases that use the Windows.Services.Store namespace

Tags: windows, uwp, store

I'm updating an existing app to Windows 10 UWP from Windows 8.1 and thought I should utilise the latest Windows.Services.Store namespace for license and in app purchases.  I followed the instructions for testing and submitted a package to the store which I downloaded to get the license and associated again to start debugging.

Upon debugging, I expected to be able to set the purchase success/failure response through a popup dialog as occurs under the Windows.ApplicationModel.Store namespace.

However all I get is a request to input my credit card details, etc and I'm unable to get past that to test the rest of the process.

In addition, as this is an App with existing customers, as Microsoft instructions suggest, I set this beta submission to not appear in the store and only be visible to those with a direct link, yet it appears that existing customers have access to this beta version as the stats show acquisitions.

I've researched this but the best advice I saw was the suggestion to set the cost of licenses and addons in the store to zero and set their expiration date to a day so they can be purchased repeatedly.  But surely this makes licenses and addons available to existing customers for free and only allows testing of one purchase per day?

Frankly, using the live Store as part of the testing process seems reckless, especially as Microsoft don't provide details of how to perform such testing safely.

Please tell me that there is a sensible solution to beta testing purchasing without having to buy my own licenses and addons repeatedly, because that would be almost as idiotic as making licenses and addons available for free to my customers!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're updating your **existing** Windows 8.1 apps to UWP, this [**testing guidance**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/in-app-purchases-and-trials#testing) may not apply to your specific case due to your existing customers.

If you don't want to set the add-on price for free, you could generate promotional codes for your hidden add-on product. So that you could have free access to the add-on by redeeming promo code and you could test if your add-on features work well after unlocking it in your UWP app.

You could find it from dashboard `Attract` list:

[image]

And you could select the add-on name you want to test:
[image]

Microsoft is working on optimizing the purchasing testing process for `Windows.Service.Store` namespace. If you have any suggestion about it, please feel free to submit your idea at [Windows 10 Feedback Hub](https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/store/p/feedback-hub/9nblggh4r32n).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. As I explained, I already followed the instructions in your link and it only details obtaining an initial test license. Promo codes isn't going to solve the problem of how to test code that deals with purchasing failure. Testing in the Windows.ApplicationModel.Store namespace allows simulation of such failure.  This isn't provided for in the Windows.Services.Store namespace, so there isn't a way to test all code paths in the purchasing process.  Surely Microsoft needs to actually provide a testing mechanism before Customers can make suggestions of how to "optimise" it?